# How to evaluate user-defined functions with variables?

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, variable

*I have an extremely simple question, but I couldn't find anything anywhere, maybe I didn't know what to search for, so feel free to mark it as duplicate if there **is** a duplicate.*

Let's say that I define some function, for example

`f[p_Integer] := Sum[k!/(k^2 - 3), {k, 0, p}]`.

If I want to evaluate it for some integer, for example `f[10]`, it works, as expected. But what if I want to evaluate it for a variable, for example `f[n]`, how do I tell Mathematica to do it? I get `f[n]` as the result, but that's not so useful.

*I'm interested in the **general** solution, nevermind my example, I had to use something.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you told M that the argument to `f` must have Integer head. So when you said `f[n]` and `n` is not integer, then M did not know what to do and returned back the input. If you wanted `f` to be evaluated for non integer heads, you can do

```
ClearAll[n,f,p]
f[p_Integer]:=Sum[k!/(k^2-3),{k,0,p}]
f[p_]:=Sum[k!/(k^2-3),{k,0,p}]  (*or can also use f[p_Symbol]*)
```

Now

```
f[5]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[n]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It is useful to note that `f[5] == (f[n] /. n -> 5)` evaluates to `True`, i.e., the `DifferenceRoot` gives the same result as the integer input. Consequently, while the definition for integer input is efficient, it is computationally redundant.

Comment: Great, thank you, I really needed the `f[p_Integer]` specification, so I didn't know how to do both, this works!